# How do I add error bars in ggplot barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to find which city has the highest proportion of having kids (yes/no).

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(City = c("Manhattan", "Los Angeles", "Manhattan", 
"Boston", "Dallas", "Los Angeles", "Dallas", "Los Angeles", "Dallas", 
"Manhattan", "Boston", "Manhattan"), Has_Kids = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Right now I have the code to find the mean, but I would like to also add error bars to see any significant:

```
df %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(`Kids Percent` = 100 * mean(Has_Kids == 1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = City, y = `Kids Percent`, fill = City)) +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = round(`Kids Percent`, 2)),
    vjust = -0.3,
    size = 2.5,
    na.rm = TRUE
  ) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", na.rm = TRUE) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Kids by City [Proportion]",
       x = "City", y = "%") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(
         angle = 90,
         vjust = 0.5,
         hjust = 1
       ))
```

[image]

Edit: i'm also open to other/potentially better to visualize these data. My real dataset is similar in nature, but I have around 200k rows. Please suggest any better visualization methods if you know of any.

Comment: Take a look at `geom_errorbar()`

Comment: Error bars on barplots are often cited as bad practice. Dotplots can be nicer. Switch your x and y axes and use `geom_point()` instead of `geom_bar()`. Then you can use `geom_errorbar()` still.

Comment: But your first step needs to be to calculate the interval you want the error bars to span. [This thread offers advice on that](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/207807/7515). Since you have some extreme values (Boston and LA) you may find the bootstrap method nicer than the normal approximation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a high enough reputation to comment, so I'm forced to "answer".

These sort of plots (sometimes called dynamite plots because they look like a cartoonish stick of dynamite with a wick poking out) are not regarded particularly highly because they do not communicate the structure of the data very effectively.

Consider [*Dynamite Plots Mist Die*](https://simplystatistics.org/posts/2019-02-21-dynamite-plots-must-die/), which contains some alternatives (in ggplot).

Comment: Very interesting, I actually was not aware of this discussion. Thank you for bringing it to my attention!